# List of matrices from dataframe

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to convert a data frame into a list matrices for each group within my data set (each group has different number of individuals).
The column containing actor names should be the rows and the receiver columns should be the columns, in the matrix. Lastly, the matrix should be filled with the numbers from another columns.
The data frame looks something like this -

```
Group   Actor Receiver Count
  A      AA      AB        3
  A      AA      AH        6
  A      AB      AH        3
```

...

And I would like to convert it to

```
[[A]]
           [,AA] [,AB] [,AC] [,AH]
    [AA,]    0      3     0     6
    [AB,]    0      0     0     3
    [AC,]    0      0     0     0
    [AH,]    0      0     0     0
```

followed by matrices for other groups.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example, with another 3 rows but of group B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could split the data by 'Group' and use `xtabs`

```
lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$Group), function(x) 
   {
    lvls <- sort(unique(c(unlist(x[1:2]), "AC")))
    x[1:2] <- lapply(x[1:2], factor, levels = lvls)
    xtabs(Count ~ Actor + Receiver, data = x)
   })
```

-output

```
$A
     Receiver
Actor AA AB AC AH
   AA  0  3  0  6
   AB  0  0  0  3
   AC  0  0  0  0
   AH  0  0  0  0
```

---

If we need to convert back

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$Group), function(x) 
    {
     lvls <- sort(unique(c(unlist(x[1:2]), "AC")))
     x[1:2] <- lapply(x[1:2], factor, levels = lvls)
     as.data.frame(xtabs(Count ~ Actor + Receiver, data = x))
    })
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, Group = names(lst1), lst1))
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out
   Group Actor Receiver Freq
1      A    AA       AA    0
2      A    AB       AA    0
3      A    AC       AA    0
4      A    AH       AA    0
5      A    AA       AB    3
6      A    AB       AB    0
7      A    AC       AB    0
8      A    AH       AB    0
9      A    AA       AC    0
10     A    AB       AC    0
11     A    AC       AC    0
12     A    AH       AC    0
13     A    AA       AH    6
14     A    AB       AH    3
15     A    AC       AH    0
16     A    AH       AH    0
```

---

Or may also convert to a 3D array with `xtabs` and reconvert with `as.data.frame`

```
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(df1[2:3])))
as.data.frame(xtabs(Count ~ Actor + Receiver + Group, 
  transform(df1, Actor = factor(Actor, levels = lvls), 
   Receiver = factor(Receiver, levels = lvls))))
```

---

We may be able to expand the data without having to reshape and then reconvert

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
    complete(Actor = sort(unique(c(Actor, Receiver, "AC"))),
            Receiver =  sort(unique(c(Actor, Receiver, "AC"))), 
       fill = list(Count = 0)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   Group Actor Receiver Count
   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int>
 1 A     AA    AA           0
 2 A     AA    AB           3
 3 A     AA    AC           0
 4 A     AA    AH           6
 5 A     AB    AA           0
 6 A     AB    AB           0
 7 A     AB    AC           0
 8 A     AB    AH           3
 9 A     AC    AA           0
10 A     AC    AB           0
11 A     AC    AC           0
12 A     AC    AH           0
13 A     AH    AA           0
14 A     AH    AB           0
15 A     AH    AC           0
16 A     AH    AH           0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A"), Actor = c("AA", "AA", 
"AB"), Receiver = c("AB", "AH", "AH"), Count = c(3L, 6L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Try `lapply(split(df[-1], df[[1]]), xtabs, formula = Count ~ .)`

Comment: @Nitrowast3 please check the update

Comment: For some reason the Group is getting added as the first entry in the row. Is there a way I can drop it ?

Comment: @Nitrowast3 you meant the row names.  You can assign it to NULL.  Please check the update

Comment: Yes that is a much easier method. Thank you!!